# Why are the values same?

Tags: c

I am unable to understand this piece of code. I cannot understand why the values of sx, sa, sy are the same , meaning 42. I understand it has to do somthing with the pointers. If someone could explain

```
#include <stdio.h> 

static int sx;
static int sa[100];
static int sy;

int main() {
    int *p;
    for(p=&sx; p <=&sx+200; p++) 
    {
        *p = 42;
    }   
    printf("sx = \t%i\n",sx);
    printf("sa[0] = \t%i\n",sa[0]);
    printf("sa[109] = \t%i\n",sa[109]);
    printf("sy = \t%i\n",sy);

    getchar();
}
```

Comment: It's called "undefined behavior." You're lucky you didn't open a black hole and kill us all.

Comment: To respond to the now deleted comment about why it doesn't give an error: "undefined behavior" means the behavior is literally undefined. That is to say, *anything can happen as a result of what was done*. If the C standard required an error to be given, then the behavior would be *defined* (not *un*defined) (it would just be defined to give you an error). Undefined behavior has a complete lack of definition of what will happen when you do something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are writing beyond the bounds of a variable and so it is **undefined behavior**.

```
for(p=&sx; p <=&sx+200; p++) 
{
    *p = 42;
}
```

This code fragment writes beyond the memory which was allocated for `sx` and causes undefined behavior. Note `p` is pointer to `sx` and `sx` is only a single integer and not an array. The loop iterates and writes beyond the memory which is allocated for `sx`.

Undefined Behavior does not necessarily mandate a program crash, it simply means that the output of the program can be anything. It might appear to work or not or show some strange results, in simple words any result is possible.

Comment: so should it not give an error rather than giving out the correct value?

Comment: @Mani: *Undefined Behavior* means the behavior is undefined. It might give you an error, it might not. It's totally undefined.

Comment: @Mani: you've written `p <=&sx+200;` as your loop control condition - for better or in this case worse the program *trusts* you the programmer. If you were doing it properly, any extra run-time checks injected by the compiler would slow the program down for no benefit, and compile-time analysis gets prohibitively complicated (and below that threshold still potentially significantly costly in time compiling). Other languages value safety over performance - not C.

Answer (score 5):

This code makes the assumption that the memory layout of your static data looks like this:

```
+----+-----------------------------+----+
| sx | sa .....                    | sy |
+----+-----------------------------+----+
```

Thus, the array is "bounded" by `sx` and `sy`, so that using their addresses as boundaries includes all the elements of `sa`. In this case also, it's using `&sx + 200` which likely covers `sa` and then quite a bit more (remember, pointer arithmetic is scaled).

Strictly speaking, this is undefined behavior and you can't depend on this. But, that is why it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

First, your overwriting memory there. So if you want to play with pointers change this:

```
for(p=&sx; p <=&sx+200; p++)
```

to:

```
for(p=&sx; p <=&sy; p++)
```

Now, What you're doing there is to overwrite every memory position between `sx` and `sy` with the value 42. And it happens that `sx`, `sy` and every element of `sa` are in those memory addresses.

And BTW the code makes assumptions about memory arrangements that may not be true in every computer.

Comment: Merely doing `&sx <= &sy` is undefined behavior as well. Surprise.